# Possible to install Spider Queen mod on an Amazon Fire Tablet?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-mods

My niece wanted the Minecraft [Spider Queen mod](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/search?search=spider%20queen) on her Amazon Fire Tablet.  I tried to install the mod from curseforge (linked above), but I was unsuccessful.

Is it even possible to install on a Fire tablet?  I'm not a Minecraft player, so I don't know the go-to for installing any mods, let alone this specific one, nor am I familiar with Fire tablets, so keep that in mind when answering (i.e. explain it like I'm 5).

FYI, I don't know what type of Minecraft install she has.  I don't live near her, so I wouldn't be able to try any answer or answer questions about my question until the next visit, which may be months from now.

Comment: Oh geez. I posted this as a guest. I didn't know it would create a separate account. How do I link them?

Answer (score 1):

#### It isn't possible

The mod you listed is for the [Java](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition) version of Minecraft. You are unable to load Java mods on the [Bedrock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition) edition of Minecraft.

If you wanted to install custom made items such as texture packs or maps, you can find them on the [Minecraft Marketplace](https://marketplace.minecraft.net/en-us) within the game.

**Note:** Some items in the Marketplace cost real money.

Comment: I’d pick your answer, but I don’t know how to deal with having accidentally created a guest account to ask this question. Is there a way to merge it with my real account?

Comment: I don’t have a password for either account. My original is linked to Facebook and the other doesn’t have a password created yet. Each has a different email.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to merge them. You could always contact support at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/contact